# Prevent of inputting string into double var. Java

Tags: java

I'm so sorry, for, maybe, such a stupid question..

I need to get positive double, and to prevent from inputing string into it (so from getting an exception).
I've already tried to do something with exceptions but have got confused much more..

```
boolean check=false;
    while (!check) {
    if (PerConst.hasNextDouble() && !(PerConst.nextDouble()<0))
    {
        m = PerConst.nextDouble();
        check=true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid number, Enter positive double: ");
        PerConst.next();
    }}
```

so when i try to (input string which cant be converted into double) or (double which is less then zero) i need to get a message "Invalid number, Enter positive double: " and enter once more, if it's again not correct then get that messaged and again and again..

but in this case (when i have that code) i have this intupr and outputs..

```
qw
Invalid number, Enter positive double: 
rt
Invalid number, Enter positive double: 
-12
Invalid number, Enter positive double: 
-13 //ink why i have to enter 2 numbers.. 
-34
Invalid number, Enter positive double: 
-1
-2
Invalid number, Enter positive double: 
2 //this one is ok, but again i have to enter 2 more num, and just the last one counts
3
4
4.0 //i read that var after getting out of that loop
```

I'd be really thankful if somebody can help me with that.
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `nextDouble()` in your loop.

Every time you call that method, the next double is returned, you should do it like this:

```
boolean check=false;
while (!check && PerConst.hasNextDouble()) {
    m = PerConst.nextDouble();
    if (m >= 0) 
        check=true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid number, Enter positive double: ");
    }
}
if(!check) {
    // System.in has reached EOF
}
```

This loop only calls nextDouble one time, so its value is preserved